# make textfield of cell that is not visible as first responder

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Working on a login form with multiple fields.

When user click on **Next**/**Done**(Default buttons) button of keyboard, next text field should become a first responder.

`TextField` is in `UITableViewCell`. When user click on **Done** button, I fetch the next cell and make its text field as a first responder. But if next cell is not visible then next text field does not become first responder.

How to fix this problem?

```
func makeTextFieldFirstResponder(textField:UITextField) -> Bool {
    let row = textField.tag
    let indxPath = IndexPath(row: textField.tag + 1, section: 0)
    if let cell = tblEditViewDetail.cellForRow(at: indxPath) as? InputCell {
        cell.txtField.firstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can your code or screen shot where you stuck

Comment: CellForRow is coming nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs for `cellForRow` :](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow)

> An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

So if the cell is not visible, the return value should be `nil`. You should first use [`scrollToRow`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow), and then get cell and set first responder.

Answer (score 1):

Let do a trick.

1) Save your next textfield index of cell with be first responder.

```
var respondTextFieldIndex: Int = 0

func makeTextFieldFirstResponder(textField:UITextField) -> Bool {
     let row = textField.tag 
     let indxPath = IndexPath(row: textField.tag + 1, section: 0)

     respondTextFieldIndex= textField.tag + 1

     if let cell = tblEditViewDetail.cellForRow(at: indxPath) as? InputCell {
    cell.txtField.firstResponder()
}
```

2) In `cellForRow` function, if your next cell has index equal `respondTextFieldIndex`let set it `firstResponder`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = *Your work here*.

    if indexPath.row == respondTextFieldIndex {
       cell.txtField.firstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: This will set the textfield as first responder when te cell is dequeued. From what I understood OP wanted this to happen automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Use Below code this code is use for you.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return arrData.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddEventCell", for: indexPath) as! AddEventCell
        cell.txtName.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.txtName.delegate = self
        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }

    public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        if textField.tag < arrData.count - 1  {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            tbl.viewWithTag(textField.tag+1)?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else
        {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: How does that solve OPs issue? What is `tbl` in `textfieldShouldReturn`? How does it refernce an invisible cell?